# Scala package object getClass

Tags: java, scala

I want to get `java.lang.Class` for Scala package object:

app/package.scala:

```
package object app {
}
```

app/Main.scala:

package app

```
object Main extends App {
  val _ = app.getClass
}
```

Compilation fails with:

> object getClass is not a member of package app Note that app extends
>   Any, not AnyRef. Such types can participate in value classes, but
>   instances cannot appear in singleton types or in reference
>   comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define method inside app returning class:

```
package object app {
  def cls = getClass
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Nyavro for the answer.

It seems that package object restricts access to its built-in member from outside and to get full access to package object as to plain object we can do following:

```
package object app {
  val instance = this
}
```

and use it like:

```
app.instance.getClass
```